# Configuring DNS server on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, ip-address, nslookup

I have successfully setup a DNS server on my local virtual machine and its running and I've mapped 2 public IP's with my domain name (****.com). I also created reverse lookup zones which basically map my IP's to the domain name... Once I did this, I've typed the following in cmd:

```
nslookup

entered IP <- i get back correct result 

entered domain name <- i get back correct result
```

I entered this command in my windows server 2012 R2 virtual machine...

So now comes the ultimate question?? How do I actually now use this DNS server to point my domain to them in real life (not just this virtual server). When I do nslookup from a real machine (not virtualized) i don't get any results back?? How do I map now my IP's to my domain in real PC's (if we can call it like that?).

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have created necessary records at DNS zone of your domain like:

NS ...Pointing to your public IP address. (n1.example.com and ns2.example.com)
WWW ...Pointing to your public IP address.(www.example.com)
blank ...Pointing to your public IP address. (example.com)
* ... Pointing to your public IP address.(*.example.com)
MX records (If you are going to host email server) (MX -> FQDN)

Here DNS part is done. Now, you will have to register custom/private nameservers at Registrar. You can contact your Registrar to register custom nameservers on your domain with server IP address. You can have nameservers like:

ns1.example.com ......your server public IP address 
ns2.example.com ......your server public IP address

Once nameservers have been registered, you will have to host the website in IIS and set nameservers you have registered. Once these nameservers become live, you can set them for all your website hosted in same server.